# How to override service name in WSDL with Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, soap, wsdl

I'm using Delphi XE2 to create webservice application. However I need to define the service name according to external specification.

Delphi is adding "service" to service name by default. Is it possible to override this?

The 'service' is added in TWebServEx.GenerateWSDL method (Soap.WebServExp, line 261).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`OnAfterPublishingWSDL`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Soap.WSDLPub.TWSDLHTMLPublish.OnAfterPublishingWSDL) event of your `TWSDLHTMLPublish` component to change the service name:

```
procedure TMyWebModule.WSDLHTMLPublishAfterPublishingWSDL(const WSDLDoc: IWSDLDocument);
begin
  WSDLDoc.Definition.Attributes[SName] := 'MyServiceName';
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very sorry, but you can't change so behavior of library by program interfaces. It's hardcoded in the unit Soap.WSDLIntf (`const SService = 'service';`). If you are using

```
    procedure TMyWebModule.WSDLHTMLPublishAfterPublishingWSDL(const WSDLDoc: IWSDLDocument);
    begin
       WSDLDoc.Definition.Attributes[SName] := 'MyServiceName';
    end;
```

you obtain tag `"name = MyServiceName"` in XML header, but the export service name still will be with 'service' addition.

The solution is to rebuild Delphi SOAP library.

1. Change secutity settings for folder %DELPHIDIR%\Source\soap to allow domain users for read/write.
2. Find in Soap.WSDLIntf line `SService = 'service';` in `const` section.
3. Replace it with:

   ```
   {$IFDEF TRUNCATE_WSDL_EXTERNAL_NAME }
   SService = ''; 
   {$ELSE }
   "SService = 'service';
   {$ENDIF }
   ```
4. Add define name TRUNCATE_WSDL_EXTERNAL_NAME into your project.
5. Add into your project all files from %DELPHIDIR%\Source\soap.
6. Rebuild your application. If you recieve some errors "E2010 Incompatible types: 'Boolean' and 'Truncated'" typically it can happen in dpr file of your project, add prefix "system." to boolean constants "true" or "false", for example:
   `Result := system.True;`
7. Enjoy.